# Android - AudioRecord: Detect a pulse-width modulated signal over the audio jack (mic)

Tags: java, android, performance, android-audiorecord

I try to dectect a square wave signal over the audio jack in near real time (Mic). For that reason I use the class AudioRecord in streaming mode. But my problem is, that my phone (mic) always works different. Sometimes I use a threshold of 20'000 and sometimes I have to adjust my threshold to 1'000 to detect the edge (of the first pulse). The voltage range of the signal is 0 to 3V. I'm not sure if my mic isn't working right or if the adc use different reference voltages?!

I haven't got any idea how to solve this problem.
I really hope you can help me.

Here my source code:

public class ReceiveCom extends AsyncTask  implements Layers{

```
private AudioRecord audioRecord;
private int sampleRate = 44100;

private short[] audioData;
private int sizeInShorts;

private boolean isRunning=false;
private int receiveBuffer;

private int minBuffersize;
private boolean ready=false;

private int audioResult,dataCounter=0;
private short[] dataBits = new short[8];

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public ReceiveCom(){
    try{
        minBuffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, 
                                                     AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);


        audioRecord = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, 
                                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBuffersize);


        if (audioRecord.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED){   
            throw new Exception("AudioRecord init failed");
        }

        audioData = new short[2*minBuffersize];
        Log.e("ERROR", "ReceiveCom constructor: OK ");
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        Log.e("ERROR", "IllegalArgumentException: " + e);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("ERROR", "ConstructorException: " + e);           
    }
    finally{
        Log.e("ERROR", "ReceiveCom constructor: END ");
    }

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
        if(AutomaticGainControl.isAvailable()){
            Log.e("INFO", "AGC is available");
            //AutomaticGainControl.create(audioRecord.getAudioSessionId());
        }
    }
}


protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {       
    audioRecord.setPositionNotificationPeriod(minBuffersize);
    audioRecord.setRecordPositionUpdateListener( new OnRecordPositionUpdateListener(){

        @Override   
        public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord myRecorder) {
            int timeCounter=0,bitCounter=0,i=0;
            boolean edgeTriggered=false, bitReady=false;
            int dB,edgeThreshold=10000,idleThreshold=edgeThreshold/5;

            for(i=2; i<audioResult; i=i+1){
                if(edgeTriggered==false &&  audioData[i-2]<=idleThreshold && audioData[i-1]>=edgeThreshold && audioData[i]>=edgeThreshold ){
                    Log.e("DEBUG","audioData["+i+"]: "+audioData[i]);
                    timeCounter++;
                    edgeTriggered=true;
                    bitReady=false;
                }   
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onMarkerReached(AudioRecord recorder) { }
    });

    audioRecord.startRecording();
    while(isRunning){
        audioResult = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBuffersize);    
    }

    audioRecord.stop();
    audioRecord.release();  
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You should not expect the audio channel to pass the DC component of the signal, however any constant offset voltage present on the input may appear briefly then decay.  Likely you will need to build a tracking scheme for both amplitude and offset into your decoder.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there's an AGC or other pre-processing-filter on MIC. You can try AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION instead of AudioSource.MIC...